# Regex match limited number of words

Tags: regex, match

I need to match a limited number of words with regex. For example matching at most 2 words from a sentence.

EDIT: I'm using CoffeeScript and I tried

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[^a-zA-Z0-9]*){1,3}
```

which seems to be working on http://rubular.com/r/ncNgZBo6Lq but not on my script. So probably it's not supported on this implementation.

Comment: In what language? And what did you try?

Comment: The easiest way: count spaces + 1. Then add `if`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which regex implementation you are using and on exactly what you mean by "word".  One interpretation of your request would afford this regex as a solution:

```
/(\w+)\W+(\w+)/
```

To many regex engines, the `\w` represents a "word character", and the `\W` represents any character that is *not* a "word character".  In contrast to simply looking for whitespace, that will pick up words separated only by punctuation as separate words, such as in series-of-hyphenated-words.   Be careful, however, as what "word character" means to your regex engine may not be exactly what you want it to mean.  For example, the above probably counts contractions such as "don't" as two words (but perhaps that's ok).

More generally, if you can create a regex that matches every individual "word" (whatever that means to you) but not anything else, then you can form a regex as

```
/(one-word-regex)regex-for-what-can-separate-words(one-word-regex)/
```

.

Comment: I'm using CoffeeScript so I'm guessing the regex from Javascript. Scratch that I didn't use it properly